# Clone the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a requirement to add multiple input boxes to enter the data. Initially there will be only one input box and there is an "Add" button next to each generated input boxes to generate multiple text boxes.

If you look at my fiddle there are 3 levels of text boxes in 1st level it has option to enter only 1 level of data but when it comes to level 2, there should be an option to create second level of same parent block so that we can enter the sub data of the main heading. For example If I write State name then I should be able to enter sub categories..

Here is the code for the 1st level menu

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(":radio").click(function(){
         $(".test").hide();
         var show = $(this).attr("data-show");
         $("#"+show).show(300)
     });
        $('.sort').hide();
        $filtr = $('.filtr');

        $filtr.on('click', '.add', function(){
            $(this).closest('.loop').clone().appendTo( $(this).closest('.test') );

            $('.sort').show();
        });

        $filtr.on('click', '.del', function(){
           $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
        });

        $('#1lev, #2lev, #3lev').hide();

     //For sort up/down
     function moveUp(item) {
    var prev = item.prev();
    if (prev.length == 0)
        return;
    prev.css('z-index', 999).css('position','relative').animate({ top: item.height() }, 250);
    item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: '-' + prev.height() }, 300, function () {
        prev.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.insertBefore(prev);
    });
}
function moveDown(item) {
    var next = item.next();
    if (next.length == 0)
        return;
    next.css('z-index', 999).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: '-' + item.height() }, 250);
    item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: next.height() }, 300, function () {
        next.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.insertAfter(next);
    });
}

$(".filtr").sortable({ items: ".loop", distance: 10 });
$(document).on("click", "button.sort", function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var val = btn.val();
    if (val == 'up')
        moveUp(btn.parents('.loop'));
    else
        moveDown(btn.parents('.loop'));
});

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/9/)**

Required result

[image]

How to clone the `class="filtr" div` as second level panel which works exactly the same as 1st level panel?

Comment: and what is the question ??

Comment: I need to clone the entire class="filtr" div to create second level menu

Answer (score 2):

Use the `jquery clone` function for this

like,

```
newfiltr=$('.filtr').clone();
//Append newfiltr where you want
```

Docs http://api.jquery.com/clone/

**Updated**

Have you tried this,

```
$('button.level').on('click',function(){
   var $parent=$(this).closest('.filtr');
   var $clone=$parent.clone();
   $parent.after($clone);
});
```

**Second updated**

Try,

```
$('button.level').on('click',function(){
   var $parent=$(this).closest('.filtr');
   var $clone=$parent.clone();
   $clone.find('button.level').remove();
   $parent.after($clone);
});
```

Comment: I am aware of jquery clone and I have used it in my current code. All I want is to clone the main div by clicking on the > button. It would be great if you can show in  my fiddle. I tried my best but didnt get

Comment: @Sowmya Check the above answer I h've made changes in it.

Comment: But when it generates the new panel the > button should not be there, I just need to show the 1st level type input with only add, up and down button And by clicking on the  second level Add button it should generate the multiple input boxes jus like 1st level menu.

Comment: TO be simple only parent rows should have > symbol and row created by clicking on the > button should not have > button again

Comment: Please have a look at the updated image, you may get clear picture

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the solution